# react-google-maps marker animation

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

Is there a way to animate a marker on [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) from another component outside the maps? My specific requirement is to be able to click on an item in a list that animates the marker on the map for two seconds. It would be good to not have to re-render the markers.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking at the documentation and the `animation` property says its type is `any` and I am not sure what kind of property value would that be.

Answer (score 8):

`animation` prop should be a number from 1 or 2.

1 is equal to `window.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE`.

2 is equal to `window.google.maps.Animation.DROP`.

so to create a marker with animation it should be as following:

```
<Marker
position={position}
animation={window.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
/>
```

or

```
<Marker
position={position}
animation={2}
/>
```

And if you want to remove the BOUNCE animation use `animation={null}`.

You can start your app with marker `state={ animation : 2 }`(DROP animation) then change to `state={ animation: 1 }` using `setState({ animation : 1 })`(BOUNCE animation) and you can stop the BOUNCE animation using `setState({ animation: null })`

Check this [Marker animation example on google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#animate)